# Diferença entre @Deprecated e @deprecated

Tags: java, deprecated, javadoc

Qual é a diferença entre `@Deprecated` como anotação na classe e `@deprecated` na documentação da mesma? Quando usar uma e quando usar a outra?

```
/**
 * Combo box that shows the status of playlist items.
 *
 * @deprecated Use CustomComboBox from Custom-UI.
 */
@Deprecated
public class CustomComboBox extends JComboBox {}
```

Obrigado.

Comment: talvez possa ajudar  [guide on deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[@Deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) é uma anotação interpretada em tempo de compilação, para indicar que o método/classe esta depreciado. Isso irá gerar warnings e marcações na IDE quando você utilizar algum recurso depreciado.

[@deprecated](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@deprecated) é uma tag de javadoc, para documentar algum detalhe sobre a depreciação do método/classe. Normalmente nessa documentação é explicado o porque da depreciação e o que utilizar como substituição. Só faz sentido utilizar esta documentação se você de fato possui o elemento sendo documentado marcado como `@Deprecated`

Por exemplo:

```
/**
 * Método que faz alguma coisa
 * @deprecated Esse método possui uma falha muito grave e não deve ser utilizado, agora deve-se utilizar {@link #metodoFazAlgoMelhorado()}.
 */
@Deprecated
public void metodoFazAlgo() {
    // ...
}

public void metodoFazAlgoMelhorado() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ótimo! muito obrigado